# the service instance will remain suspended until administratively resumed or terminated following error exception type initializer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2013

I am getting the above error, **exception type initializer**.
Could please give  what type of take an action to resolved this issue.
I got following error when am trying to drop a file in receive location and I did resumed in biztalk admin console it shows same error in event application logs.

[image: Error image]

Comment: http://blog.eldert.net/using-64bit-host-instance/

Comment: It is better to add the error as text, that way it is becomes searchable via search engines.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error due to your logging component, your logging component is trying to load itself via a static constructor most likely and failing there. It looks like it depends on Microsoft enterprise logging block, make sure you have all dependencies installed in GAC properly or check your logging component configuration to see why it's failing. It's not related to BizTalk issue.